# How to query native html elements when testing a React application with Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

When I render React elements, for example, a Button, then an equivalent HTML button element is created in the DOM.

But, when I query the DOM I'm still getting a wrapped element.

```
HTMLButtonElement {
      '__reactInternalInstance$gt1haeiqrhv': FiberNode {
        tag: 5,
        key: null,
        ...
}
```

Why don't I get the native element as if I rendered a normal div using JSDOM?
Is there a way to get it?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have to query for [`getDOMNode`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/getDOMNode.html):

```
const button = wrapper.find('button').getDOMNode();
// const button = wrapper.getDOMNode(); // <---if wrapper is button element
```

It will give you the lying dom element in the component.

Comment: You are referring here to Enzyme, which is another wrapper on top of React. Accessing getDOMNode will just give me the same React wrapper I was talking about.